# Update property with spread operator in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Well, I create a function to read a set of properties (English and French) and validate whether the property has any value or not. If it is empty, its status is updated as 'Failed'. Even though it catches empty value properly, error occurs when it updates the status property. Could you let me know what I missed here?

*rowData*

```
rowData={English: "View Database Scope", French: "Afficher la portée de la base de données"}
```

*Function*

```
  const statusBodyTemplate = (rowData) => {
    const addStatus = { ...rowData, status: "Passed" };

    if (!checkEmpty(addStatus.English) || !checkEmpty(addStatus.French)) {      
      addStatus = { ...addStatus, status: "Failed" }; <<< Error occurs here.
    }
}
```

*Error message*

```
Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at Object.statusBodyTemplate [as body] (Test.js:195)
    at BodyCell.render (BodyCell.js:394)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17485)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17435)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19073)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293)
    at react-dom.development.js:11327
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11322)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11309)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21893)
    at dispatchAction (react-dom.development.js:16139)
    at Test.js:90
```

Comment: Use `let` instead of `const`

Comment: @CoryHarper It works. Thank you for reminding me about let and const.

Comment: The error is self explanatory `Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.` , declare the `addStatus` using `let` not `const`

Comment: Use let instead of const in line 2.

Comment: Alternatively assign with a ternary: `const addStatus = !checkEmpty(addStatus.English) || !checkEmpty(addStatus.French) ? { ...addStatus, status: "Failed" } : { ...rowData, status: "Passed" };`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return value from `statusBodyTemplate()`, you could try:

```js
const statusBodyTemplate = (rowData) => {
    const addStatus = { ...rowData, status: "Passed" };

    if (!checkEmpty(addStatus.English) || !checkEmpty(addStatus.French)) {      
      return { ...addStatus, status: "Failed" };
    }
    
    return addStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const statusBodyTemplate = (rowData) => {
  let addStatus = { ...rowData, status: 'Passed' };

  if (!checkEmpty(addStatus.English) || !checkEmpty(addStatus.French)) {
    addStatus = { ...addStatus, status: 'Failed' };
  }
  return addStatus
};
```